# Getting images from Google maps V2 from latitude and longitude

Tags: android, google-maps, locationmanager, google-street-view

I am making an android app for housing. This app is for people seeking housing in any location. I have the latitude and logitude for a house that is being sublet. Now i want the street view of that house so that i can display it in the application. How do i do that ?

i can't post any code coz it needs to remain confidential.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,

```
Intent streetView = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("google.streetview:cbll="+ latitude+","+longitude+"&cbp=1,99.56,,1,-5.27&mz=21"));
startActivity(streetView);
```

Make sure that you have `Street View` app installed.

Comment: Thank you. But i want a static image file of the location that i can add as icon

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18997121/using-image-from-street-view