# How to display a streetview preview

Tags: android, google-maps, google-street-view

I have included a StreetViewPanoramaFragment in my app, but I also want to show a preview of the streetview as seen in the google maps app.

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can load the street view image by using the [Google Street View Image API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/).

You can specify location and image size etc in the image request URL.

```
private static String imageURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=40.720032,-73.988354&fov=90&heading=235&pitch=10";
```

For requesting image, You can use Square's Picasso library:

```
Picasso.with(this).load(imageURL).into(imageView);
```

Or use Google's Volley library:

```
// Get the ImageLoader through your singleton class.
mImageLoader = MySingleton.getInstance(this).getImageLoader();
mImageLoader.get(imageURL, ImageLoader.getImageListener(mImageView,
         R.drawable.def_image, R.drawable.err_image));
```

Or use bitmap with stream:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(imageUrl).getContent());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

You can also check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18997296/4195406) about how to get street view image with XML.

Comment: Cool, but you must create a Google Map account and Request API Key for you to continue otherwise you will get this error from Google: **The Google Maps Platform server rejected your request. You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account**